# In Vim ex mode how to re-use a string from the default buffer in the command

Tags: regular-expression, ex-mode, range, text-generation, string-manipulation

I'm trying to modify this file, by extracting the very *first* line in the file and prepend it to each of the consecutive lines until end of the file

```
black
widow
card
Friday
berry
```

I used `ex` command (which doesn't work as expected) which prepends the string `black` from 2<sup>nd</sup> line onward without deleting the first line.

```
 ex -sc '2,$s/^/black: /|x' file
```

What I want to do?

1. Dynamically get the string `black` in the replacement part `s//<>`
2. Remove the first line after getting the string `black` in the buffer

Expected output would be

```
black: widow
black: card
black: Friday
black: berry
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? Do you want a function that will do this? Or do you want something else?

Comment: @klaus: What I meant was `black:` was hard-coded in my example, how can I identify it with the `ex` command itself - For e.g. get the first line and store it in a variable and use in the replacement section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@D.BenKnoble has already given you a terrific answer explaining all the ins and outs of batch mode, but in case you were looking for a one liner similar to the one you already tried, here's one that I think is a bit simpler than the existing ones in the current answers:

```
ex -sc 'norm!ggy$dd' -c '%norm!i^R0: ' -c 'x' file
```

The first `:normal` command moves to the start of the file `gg`, yanks the contents of the line `y$`, and then deletes the line itself `dd`. We yank before deleting because we don't want the newline.

We run the second `:normal` command on every line by means of a `%` range, inserting the contents of the yank register `"0`—i.e. the original first line—followed by the required colon and space.

*N.B. The slight technicality here is that the `^R` you see in the middle of the command is actually a literal `CTRL-R` character—which you can probably enter in your shell by typing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>: you cannot copy/paste the whole command from this answer. For a copy-pastable version, we need to add the character using a string literal and then execute it:*

```
ex -sc 'norm!ggy$dd' -c 'exe "%norm!i\<C-R>0: "' -c 'x' file
```

The third simply saves the file and quits Vim, as in the command you already tried.

**Extra credit**: Finally, here's a version that replaces a little complexity in the first ex command with a bunch in the second:

```
ex -sc '1d a' -c '%norm!i^Ra^[kJi:' -c 'x' file
                         ^^ ^^
```

This time we have two literal control characters: a `CTRL-R` and an `ESC` (denoted by `^[`, entered via <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>), which we use to remove the newline included when we used the ex `:delete` command to delete the entire line into register `"a`.

Comment: Thanks, don't know i can enter literal character in shell. Nice trick with `J` to deal with line break.

Answer (score 4):

## Using `ex`

Ex is the command-line successor to the venerable `ed`, a line-oriented editor.
You can access ex-mode from vim by typing `Q` (unless you have it mapped). `gQ`
gives an improved ex-mode. See `:help Ex-mode`.

You can also start `ex` from the command line, just like `vim`:

```
ex {file}
```

Then you type your commands, and `ex` does them.

All the `:`-style commands available in `vim` are available to `ex`.

### Scripting `ex`

There are scriptable ways of giving commands to `ex`. We focus on

1. `sourcing` a file
2. standard input

#### Sourcing a file

Write a (vim)script in a file, then do

```
ex -S {script.vim} {file}
```

Your script is sourced (executed line for line) on the file. When it's finished,
you'll be left in `ex` as normal. We'll discuss the niceties of ending scripts
at the end.

One of the benefits of this approach is the ability to easily edit and comment
your code (e.g., from `vim`).

Another benefit is the ability to source these scripts from inside `vim` (via
`:source script.vim`), and undo them (`u`) as desired.

#### Standard Input

Since you give commands to `ex` on standard input, you can use any shell technique
to pass commands to it. For example, with bash, any of the following should
work:

```
ex {file} <<EOF
{script text}
EOF

# or

ex {file} <{script.vim}

# or

ex {file} < <(cat <<DOG
{script text}
DOG
)
```

This has the benefit that the entire contents of the 'ex-script' can be placed
in (human-readable!) form in a shell script.

#### Script considerations

What is the purpose of the script?

If it is intended to perform some changes to a file on disk, it should end with
the line `wq` or a variation thereof, in order to write and quit.

If the script is just a pre-cursor to normal editing (and for you only), you can
end with `visual` to drop you into Normal-mode of full-on `vim`.

Otherwise, just let it end and drop you into interactive mode.

## Solution

Finally, a script to suit your needs:

```
" Delete first line into register z
1 delete z
" Eliminate newlines
let @z = substitute(@z, '\v\n', '', 'g')
" Put the contents from the first line on all the others
" cf. :help sub-replace-special
%substitute/^/\=printf('%s: ', @z)/
" Optional
" write
" quit
```

If using a heredoc syntax in the shell, you may need to eliminate the comments
entirely (delete them), since shell-quoting and comments may get in the way of
vim seeing the comments. In interactive and source use, commented lines are
perfectly fine.

---

I've run `ex -S script.vim test.txt` with the bottom two lines uncommented,
where `test.txt` was

```
black is the color of my true love's hair
widow
card
Friday
berry
```

And received as the new version

```
black is the color of my true love's hair: widow
black is the color of my true love's hair: card
black is the color of my true love's hair: Friday
black is the color of my true love's hair: berry
```

Comment: I've not left a detailed explanation of the script itself other than the comments; hopefully it is self-explanatory, and the help provides good enough reference. If not, I can update it. I focused on the `ex` usage, since that seemed to be OPs point of difficulty.

Comment: Perhaps a bit easier: `:%s/^/\=@z.': '/` no need for the `printf()` function.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt good call on the beginning of line replacement. I do tend to find string concatenation hard to read, and the printf makes it clear where things go, letting me see the structure of the whole string. YMMV

Comment: Can ex read command from stdin ? I tried, but failed. The `man` page says -S doesn't support `-`.

Comment: `-S` takes the name of a file. You can use process substitution to give it one though. `ex -S <(create your contents here`. I’m not sure if `ex -S -` or `ex -S /dev/stdin` would work... but ` { cat - > /tmp/tempfile && ex -S /tmp/tmpfile }` would work and could read from stdin or a pipe. Dont forget to remove tmpfile when done via trap.

Answer (score 3):

```
ex -s +'norm! gg"adiwdd' +'exec printf("%%s/^/%s : /", @a)' +'x' ex_txt
```

- `norm! gg"adiwdd` delete `black` in 1st line to register a, delete first line
- `exec printf("%%s/^/%s : /", @a)` add content of register a to start of every line. You can get content of register a via `@a` or `getreg('a')` in ex mode . check `:h printf()` if you have problem with `%%`.
- `x` save and exit

I'm new to this area, there might be other ways to access register in ex mode.

**update**

`vim -u NONE -Es +'norm! gg"adiwdd' +'exec printf("%%s/^/%s : /", @a)' +'x' ex_txt`

OP had to add `-u NONE` to make it work, that's very weird, i have no idea what kind of setting or plugin would make `ex` broken.

Comment: I tried this on my sample file, and it remained the same after running the command. may be I'm missing something in my vim config? I'm running Vim 7.4

Comment: trye `vim -u NONE -Es +'norm! gg"adiwdd' +'exec printf("%%s/^/%s : /", @a)' +'x' ex_txt`

Comment: Yes it worked. Could you update the answer with the same? I'll  continue to watch out for other answers that could make this processing simpler. But appreciate your efforts for this. Thanks!

Comment: I guess your `vimrc` or plugins has something to do with this. You mensioned that some command got hanged, that's not true, it's because of `-s` supress ex mode output, if that happens again, you can use x or q to exit.   Try `ex -u NONE -s +'norm! gg"adiwdd' +'exec printf("%%s/^/%s : /", @a)' +'x' ex_txt `

Answer (score 2):

You can use registers (see `:h reg`) to store a word of a line. For you particular case, you would have to perform the following set of commands:

```
:norm! gg"zyiw
:norm! gg"_dd
:%s/^/<C-r>z: /
```

- The first command yanks the first word into the register `z` from the first line
- The second command deletes the first line into blackhole register.
- The third command is a general substitute command where `<C-r>` lets you insert content of a register (see `:h i_CTRL-R`)

Of course, you can do this some other more general and secure way, but I guess that was not your query. You wanted to know how to store contents.

Comment: Thanks but you can provide an ex mode equivalent of it.  I’m planning to use it from the command line

Comment: No, sorry. But I don't see myself using vim ex commands from command line. I always use `sed`. You can then pipe the sed commands together to achieve this.

Comment: These being ex commands, you should be able to feed them together in an ex command line.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble : I’m quit a noob using ex in command line. Could you show how to do that here? Or add an answer?

Comment: @Inian see my new answer

Comment: You don't really need to use register z or the blackhole register in this answer. Yanks are stored in the yank register, which isn't touched by the delete.

Comment: Also, `:1d` is a bit simpler than `:norm! ggdd` (See `:help :delete`)