# Add a line after 1 line after match in Ex mode

Tags: search, ex-mode

I need to search for a string in a file, then I need to some text after one line following the first match. I need to perform this for a number of files in a script.

I am trying to use vim ex mode for this. I know `:/search_string` can perform a search but I am not able to figure out how to move the cursor down and insert the line.
Will sed or awk be more suitable for this?

I need to do this in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your files into vim:

```
vim files
```

Then, we will use a command on each of them via `:argdo`. The command searches (`:/pattern/+1`) and `o`pens a new line:

```
:/pattern/+1 normal! oYour new text here
```

Another option is to `put` from the expression register

```
:/pattern/+1 put ='Your text here'
```

Altogether:

```
argdo /pattern/+1 put ='text'
```

This may struggle if any of the files don’t contain `pattern`.

From [my answer on scripting ex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19700/10604):

```
ex file <<EOF
/pattern/+1 put ='text'
wq
EOF
```

Comment: I need to do this in a script.

Comment: @In78 see my update. Next time, that is helpful information to add in the question.

Comment: I also need to add the text after one line following the match. Sorry for not being clearer in my question.

Comment: @ln78 can you provide some sample input/output? this answer puts the text on the line following the pattern. Do you mean the line following the line following the pattern? If so, try `/pattern/+1 put ='text'`

Comment: yeah this will work

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late & maybe I am misunderstanding the requirements, but you can do this in POSIX `ex`, without *vim* extensions.

Simply (a)ppend any text following a match, optionally with a number of additional lines.
The `.` is not a typo, you need that to exit the append.

For this overly complex example, `^H` is CTL+v,CTL+h (i.e. `col -b`)

```
LANG=C ex -s <<'EOF'
r!man true
g/.^H/ s///g
"%!sed "s/.`printf '\b'`//g"
/Exit/+1a
****
ALL MY STUFF
****
.
%p
wq! true.txt
EOF
```

The extras are just to give you some other ideas.
`/pattern/+1i` would do the same thing, but (i)nsert before, etc.